# Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\IBMDB2\DB2Exception

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, doctrine, debian

I had the task as administrator to upgrade a Debian server from 10 to 11. I cloned the server and gave it a different IP address and did an "apt-get upgrade" (the PHP Code would not be changed). When I was done, PHP7 gave me the error message at the website see below the code. After that I did a reboot. Unfortunately I restarted the production server that was running for our user. And now the problem is on both servers???

I am a little desperate. Does anyone have any ideas, where the error could come from?

thanks in advance...

.

.

.

.
[image]
.

An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\IBMDB2\DB2Exception

File:

```
/var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/IBMDB2/DB2Connection.php:50
```

Message:

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/IBMDB2/DB2Driver.php(57): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\IBMDB2\DB2Connection->__construct(Array, NULL, NULL, Array)
#1 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\IBMDB2\DB2Driver->connect(Array, 'M00PROD', 'd0N0K0Q08090z09...', Array)
#2 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(814): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
#3 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php(712): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT db22.* F...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php(196): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->load(Array, NULL, NULL, Array, NULL, 1, NULL)
#5 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/module/Tool/src/Tool/Service/EntityServiceAbstract.php(45): Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->findOneBy(Array)
#6 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/module/Auth/src/Auth/Controller/IndexController.php(58): Tool\Service\EntityServiceAbstract->findOneBy(Array)
#7 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Auth\Controller\IndexController->loginAction()
#8 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/module/Auth/src/Auth/Controller/IndexController.php(16): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 [internal function]: Auth\Controller\IndexController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#14 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#18 /var/www/mobtool/htdocs/public/index.php(20): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Can you share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem? Did you check whether the database packages are all installed? Sounds like one is missing

Comment: i mean yes. it worked before. what information would you need? apt? php -v?

Comment: If it worked before, what has changed? What else did you try to spot the problem, or fix it?

Comment: and that exactly the problem. i have not done anything. for example if i restore a backup 5 days ago, so before i did the upgrade on the test server. The same error comes out... I can explain it this way: when the server wants to access the db2-database-server it notices it and saves a hash. like with ssh knowhost. When this is changed it blocks both. comes the same error. but the db2 connect interface doesn't have any verification, or does it???